# Moving unmovable apps to SD Card

Tags: applications, app2sd

My target was to get enough space on my Tecno Camon CA7 running Android 8.1 and get it a 32 GB SD card but only to find out that some applications cannot allow me to transfer them to SD Card. This sounds like the legitimate law of some apps developer suggestions.

[image]
[image]

Does this mean that after rooting my device I can have access to transferring every app with storage suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.heagoo.sdcardmovable
open the app,
goto "only ROM" tab,
press and hold the app,
tap "make it movable",
"uninstall" (the original app),
"install" (the patched apk),
then check again from your app settings if the "change" (storage) button appears.
Note: the app will no be longer updated from Playstore. You lose all app data on uninstall

Comment: After installing it, it ends up only deleting my existing app and cannot re-instal the patched apk

Comment: check for android settings - security - unkown sources (this will allow installing apk)